# Prevent CSS Styles to apply to all the elements of a grid

Tags: css

I am very new to this so pardon me if my question is silly. I have several elements within a grid and most when I apply a style to the header, it automatically apply to the footer and the section. I don't know what to do to prevent that. Should I define a different class for all items to be able to assign different CSS styles?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: your question has the answer, you should follow it

Comment: You shouldn't need to define separate classes for each element, only groups of elements. I.e. different classes for the header and footer

Answer (score 0):

As a simple start it can look like this and this principle work on a web page as well as on a grid or any other nested elements.

HTML

```
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>

        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div>

        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <nav>

        </nav>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS

```
header { ... }

header nav { ... }                 // style the nav only within the header

main { ... }

main div { ... }                   // style div within the main

footer { ... }

footer nav { ... }                 // style the nav only within the footer
```